# how to set two or three times ringing sound?

Tags: android

I set custom dingdong bell sound but it ring one time . how to set two or three times ringing sound.

Here java Code,

```
 mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                mMediaPlayer = 
 MediaPlayer.create(MyRideDetailTrackRide.this, R.raw.dingdong);
                mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
              // mMediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
                mMediaPlayer.start();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int howManyTimesPlayed = 0;
mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener(){
int maxRePlayCount = 3; // set this value to replay x time

@Override
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
    if(howManyTimesPlayed < maxRePlayCount) {
      howManyTimesPlayed++;
      mediaPlayer.seekTo(0);
      mediaPlayer.start();
    }
}});
```

Comment: Perfect Solution. Thanks @hasbi

Comment: thank you, if you found the answer useful, please confirm it as a correct solution